# How can one make Emacs visually look like sublime?

Tags: themes

I found the following post:

http://www.gonsie.com/blorg/subl-to-emacs.html#the-best-from-sublime-text

I copied the code to my `.emacs` but it didn't work. Why?

code:

```
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
  '(progn
     (color-theme-initialize)
     (color-theme-dusk)
     (when (display-graphic-p)
       ;; settings for GUI emacs
       (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "#282B35"))
       (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(foreground-color . "White"))
       (set-frame-font "Inconsolata 18" nil t))))
```

Comment: I would *guess* that you either don't have a `color-theme` library installed, or that you're not loading it.  But you've failed to say what you mean by "it didn't work", so who can tell?

Comment: @phils I just brewed installed emacs from scratch and after adding that to my `.emacs` file looks the same as a newly installed emacs. Does that help?

Comment: Maybe https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorThemes will help.

Comment: @omajid I didn't know emacsSE existed. Can you help me move it there please? Thanks for telling me about it! :)

Comment: I would recommend no longer using the color-theme package, instead use the built-in themes.  There are hundreds available.

Comment: @InHarmsWay how do you do that? Why do you recommend that?

Comment: M-x load-theme. There are about a dozen default options, and you can install more. I recommend this because color-theme is no longer maintained, and the modern theme system will have more options of themes, and those themes will be more recently updated and maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Besides colour themes, where is a [sublimity package](https://github.com/zk-phi/sublimity), which incorporates some of the Sublime's features - like scrolling (last time I tried it, it was a bit laggy though) or a minimap.

Comment: how do I actually install that?

Comment: `(require 'sublimity)
(with-eval-after-load 'sublimity
   (sublimity-mode 1))`

or via use-package:

`(use-package sublimity
    :config
    (sublimity-mode 1))`

Comment: that only changes theme's, right?

Comment: not really, rather it adds a minimap and changes the scrolling. It has nothing to do with colours or font locks.